# If the potential drops across a resistor (=$V_d$) then shouldn't the potential difference be the $\epsilon-V_d$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, potential, conventions

Consider the following circuit:

Suppose a current $I$ travels in both the branches, then as the current $I$ passes through the $60$ ohm resistor, there will be a drop in the potential of $60I$. Similarly, there will be a drop of $30I$ across the $30$ ohm resistor in the second branch. By drop in potential difference, I understand that we have lost that much quantity of p.d. and therefore, I believe that the potential at point X should be $12-60I$ and the potential at Y should be $12-30I$. However, in the several problems that I've tried, this is not the case. Please explain, why?

Please note that this is **not** a Homework Problem, but a specific example which I am using to understand a concept.

[image]

Comment: What is $\epsilon$ in title?

Comment: I meant the emf

Answer (score 2):

It is sometimes easier to visualise what is happening by using the idea of potential.
To do this make one point in the circuit 0 V.
This is a totally arbitrary choice.
It is the bottom right hand corner of your circuit.
Note to make the sums easier I have change the emf of the battery to 90 V so 2 A flows through the battery and 1 A through each of the resistance branches.

[image]

The potential difference across the top 30Ω resistor is $1 \times 30 = 30$ volts so the potential of node $X$ is $+30$ volts.
For the bottom 60Ω resistor the potential difference is is $1 \times 60 = 60$ volts so the potential of node $Y$ is $+60$ volts.

So the potential difference across $YX$ is $60 - 30 = 30$ with node $Y$ at the higher potential.

If a pair of resistors in one of the branches was interchanged the potential difference across $XY$ would be zero and this is the configuration for a balanced Wheatstone bridge.

Comment: This is the best explanation I've come across so far, Thank you. Just a quick question: In the bottom branch, (containing 60 ohms, 30 ohms from left to right) can we say that the we lost 60 volts across the 60 ohms resistor and so the potential at point X is 30 volts?

Comment: As drawn the potential of point $X$ is in no way determined by the arrangement of resistors in the bottom branch.  What you can say is that there is a potential difference across the top 60Ω resistor and so the potential of node $X$ is $+90 - 60 = + 30$ V.  What you wrote is correct only because both branches have the same current through them and so the potential difference across each of the 60Ω resistors ihappens to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

> I believe that the potential at point X should be 12−60I and the
>   potential at Y should be 12−30I. However, in the several problems that
>   I've tried, this is not the case. Please explain, why?

A proper way to write this is (in terms of the node voltages and branch currents) is

$$V_X = 12V - I_X \cdot 60 \Omega$$

$$V_Y = 12V - I_Y \cdot 30 \Omega$$

Where $I_X$ denotes the current through the top-most pair of resistors and $I_Y$ denotes the current through the bottom-most pair of resistors.

For the particular resistor values given, it is the case that $I_X = I_Y$:

$$I_X  = \frac{12V}{60 \Omega + 30 \Omega} = I_Y$$

and so your equations will give the correct result.  *However*, your equations will *not* give the correct result if, for example, the bottom-right resistor value were different since that would change $I_Y$ without changing $I_X$.

Without any other information about the other problems you've tried, I can only guess that your approach failed because the two branch currents are, in general, not equal.